# Different image upload form in one page

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload, crud

I've made simple PHP & MySQL crud with two image upload button to save two image to one database in different column like:

[image]

It works fine with one upload one image and saved to database, but when I add another button to try upload two image there's no error and it cannot storred in database.

Here is my small code:

```
<?php
  include 'connection.php';

  $temp = "upload/";
  if (!file_exists($temp))
    mkdir($temp);

  $name   = $_POST['name'];
  $address         = $_POST['address'];
  $fileupload      = $_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'];
  $ImageName       = $_FILES['fileupload']['name'];
  $ImageType       = $_FILES['fileupload']['type'];

  if (!empty($fileupload)){
    $random           = rand(11111111, 99999999);
    $ImageExt       = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
    $ImageExt       = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt); // Extension
    $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
    $NewImageName   = str_replace(' ', '', $random.'.'.$ImageExt);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_upload"]["tmp_name"], $temp.$NewImageName);

    $query = "INSERT into table_fileupload (name, address, image_1, image_2) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $dewan1 = $db1->prepare($query);
    $dewan1->bind_param("sss", $name, $address, $NewImageName, $NewImageName);
    $dewan1->execute();

    echo "Success!";
  } else {
    echo "Error!";
  }
?>
```

HTML:

```
               <form id="form-data">
                 ........................
                 ........................
                 ........................

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>image 1</label>
                        <input type="file" name="fileupload" id="fileupload" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>image 2</label>
                        <input type="file" name="fileupload" id="fileupload" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="button" name="save" id="save" value="Save" class="btn btn-info mt-3" />
                    </div>
                </form>
........................................
.......................................

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $("#save").click(function(){
                const fileupload = $('#fileupload').prop('files')[0];

                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('fileupload', fileupload);
                formData.append('name', $('#name').val());
                formData.append('address', $('#address').val());

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "upload.php",
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                        document.getElementById("form-data").reset();
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Upload Error!");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
  </script>
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You send/ upload 2 file bat your code try save only one. Add foreach loop to seve all sented images. Read this https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: @WiatroBosy is 100% correct. By the way, please show your HTML codes too so that we can give you further advice

Comment: @WiatroBosy yes, i will try. thankyou.

Comment: @KenLee i hv added html code above. thankyou